# Kaminari three dots after pagination buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

Got my Kaminari working (after some setbacks) and I finally have my pagination done. After I tested it, I realized there where three dots being displayed after the last-page-arrow ([error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3G08.png)). I believe there's nothing weird with my kaminari code but I paste it below.

Kaminari config file:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.default_per_page = 10
  # config.max_per_page = nil
  # config.window = 4
  # config.outer_window = 0
  # config.left = 0
  # config.right = 0
  # config.page_method_name = :page
  # config.param_name = :page
end
```

My view:

```
<%= paginate @array %>
```

My controller:

```
  def index
    @array = Kaminari.paginate_array(Group.all).page(params[:page])

    respond_with(@array)
  end
```

Not sure if this is important but i edited the Kaminari buttons because i'm not usigng fontawesome in my project, so i change the icons to bootstrap glyphicons.

Comment: Give inspect code from browser so that we can understand from where `...` is coming ,

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer for some another newly coder like me. 
There's a file called _gap.html.erb which includes the dots when there're pages not being displeyed.

Don't know if someone will come across this, but it doesn't hurt to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but adding replacing what is in `_gap.html.erb` with the following code is a solid solution:

```
<li class='disabled'>
    <%= content_tag :a, raw(t 'views.pagination.truncate') %>  
</li>
```